# Breezejs EF BeforeSaveEntities editting savemap

Tags: entity-framework, breeze

I'm trying to add some logic into the BeforeSaveEntities method.

On the client we can add a parent record and a number of child records before hitting save.

Our parent record has two fields which can be chosen by the user and are a sort of unique identifier (but not the id). The child record also has some unique identifiers and a total field. The classes look something like this:

```
public class Parent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int Ref1 { get; set; }

    public int Ref2 { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int Ref1 { get; set; }

    public int Ref2 { get; set; }

    public int Total { get; set; }

    public int ParentId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ParentId")]
    public Parent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

In the BeforeSaveEntities I'm trying to check if a parent record with the Ref1 and Ref2 fields the same as the added entity using a second context.

If a parent record exists, I remove it from the savemap to prevent it from being re-added (this seems to work).

I then look at the child records being added (again by querying a second context), and what I'm trying to do is allow the new record to be added by leaving them in the savemap where they don't exist (but updating the parentid to link them to the existing parent record).

If a child record already exists, I want to increment the total of the existing record by the value in the added one in the savemap.

I've tried a couple of ways, but can't seem to get it working. It always seems to result in all child entries for the parent getting added again, even if there is only one new child entity in the savemap.

Apologies for the contrived classes, but hopefully this gives enough info to convey what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Can you show your BeforeSaveEntities code?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about this post.

I figured out what the problem was. When i was using the second context to determine if the parent entity exists, I was expanding the sub-entity navigation property and then using this to determine if child records existed.

I was then updating one of the properties in the parent entity and adding it to the savemap with a "modified" status, forgetting that i'd expanded the sub-entity navigation property.